# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE error triggered by order of data rows

Tags: mysql

If I try to load the same two rows of data in different order, I get an error for one try and success with the other.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `date` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `val1` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `val2` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

fail.txt

```
Date,Val1,Val2
3/30/2004,,17
4/4/2004,91.4210526315789,20
```

pass.txt

```
Date,Val1,Val2
4/4/2004,91.4210526315789,20
3/30/2004,,17
```

Same command different results

```
-> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/fail.txt' REPLACE INTO TABLE `test` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES;
<- ERROR 1265 (01000) at line 1: Data truncated for column 'val1' at row 1
-> SELECT * FROM test;
<- Empty set (0.00 sec)

-> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/pass.txt' REPLACE INTO TABLE `test` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES;
-> SELECT * FROM test;
<- +-----------+---------+------+
<- | date      | val1    | val2 |
<- +-----------+---------+------+
<- | 4/4/2004  | 91.4211 |   20 |
<- | 3/30/2004 |       0 |   17 |
<- +-----------+---------+------+
<- 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I drop the table and recreate between tries.

This is using:  mysqld  Ver 5.6.15 for osx10.7 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))

Is there anything I can do so that fail.txt will load without editing the data?

EDIT:

For what it's worth, I now believe this issue is related to the MySQL server version and/or config I'm running.  Against another mysqld (5.5.32 on Ubuntu), fail.txt loads without error.

EDIT 2:

It seems like I should be able to something like the following, but I don't know what the second argument to `REPLACE` should be.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/fail.txt' REPLACE INTO TABLE `test` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES
(date, @val1, val2)
SET val1 = REPLACE( @val1, '', '\N');
```

EDIT 3:

Figured this out:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/fail.txt' REPLACE INTO TABLE `test` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES
(date, @val1, val2)
SET val1 = IF( LENGTH( @val1 ) = 0, NULL, @val);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `EDIT 3` in the question.   The following worked for me.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/fail.txt' REPLACE INTO TABLE `test` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES
(date, @val1, val2)
SET val1 = IF( LENGTH( @val1 ) = 0, NULL, @val);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter a value in first line column `val`.

change your file from:

```
Date,Val1,Val2
3/30/2004,,17
4/4/2004,91.4210526315789,20
```

TO

```
Date,Val1,Val2
3/30/2004,0,17
4/4/2004,91.4210526315789,20
```

or see mysql documentation:

> When reading data with LOAD DATA INFILE, empty or missing columns are
>   updated with ''. If you want a NULL value in a column, you should use
>   \N in the data file. The literal word “NULL” may also be used under
>   some circumstances.

chnage it to:

```
Date,Val1,Val2
3/30/2004,\N,17
4/4/2004,91.4210526315789,20
```

Comment: Sorry, but that still doesn't explain things.  The same empty field (`,,`) works fine as part of the second row in pass.txt.

Comment: @jobu If you change it in the first file you get the error message? can you add the ddl of the table please?

Comment: DDL is included in question.  See CREATE TABLE statement.